# mysql client app sends more ciphers than I specify via command line

Tags: tls, openssl, mysql

There is a server app that supports TLSv1...TLSv1.3 with OpenSSL 3.
I'm connecting to it with mysql client app, version `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.15-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`, command line

```
mysql --ssl_ca=<path-to-ca-cert-pem> --ssl_cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

My expectation that when connecting to the server (the app), mysql only reports `ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384` as a supported cipher and thus server will use it.

Instead connection uses `TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384`. The wireshark shows that ClientHello message lists the following ciphers:

```
Cipher Suites (5 suites)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x1302)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 (0x1303)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x1301)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)
    Cipher Suite: TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0x00ff)
```

The similar behavior is when using Python client.

What makes clients extend explicitly specified cipher without any warning / notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first 4 of the unexpected ciphers are TLS 1.3 ciphers, which are not covered by this configuration option. From [the documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/ssltls-system-variables/#ssl_cipher):

> ssl_cipher
> ...
> List of permitted ciphers or cipher suites to use for
> TLS. Besides cipher names, if MariaDB was compiled with OpenSSL, this
> variable could be set to "SSLv3" or "TLSv1.2" to allow all SSLv3 or
> all TLSv1.2 ciphers. **Note that the TLSv1.3 ciphers cannot be
> excluded when using OpenSSL, even by using this system variable.**

The last (TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV) is a pseudo-cipher which is not a real cipher but more a hack, and thus also not covered by this configuration option. To cite from [RFC 5746](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5746.html#section-3.3):

> In order to enhance
> compatibility with such servers, this document defines a second
> signaling mechanism via a special Signaling Cipher Suite Value (SCSV)
> "TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV", with code point {0x00, 0xFF}.
> This SCSV is **not a true cipher suite (it does not correspond to any
> valid set of algorithms) and cannot be negotiated**.  Instead, it has
> the same semantics as an empty "renegotiation_info" extension, as
> described in the following sections.